# Scroll Inner Div back to Original Position and not page itself?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I tried the script below, what Neal suggested in [Always scroll a div element and not page itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678159/always-scroll-a-div-element-and-not-page-itself)
(bravo by the way). It worked great for my needs, although, how can you reverse the effect if they scroll from bottom to top? That way it scrolls the inner div back to it's original position, when scrolling upwards with the window scrollbar. Any hints would be great. Thank you.

```
var last_scroll = -1;

$(window).scroll(function(e){
    if($('#content').scrollTop());
    var scroll = $('#view').data('scroll');
    if(scroll == undefined){
        $('#content').data('scroll', 5);
        scroll = $('#content').data('scroll');
    } else {
        $('#content').data('scroll', scroll + 5);
        scroll = $('#view').data('scroll');
    }
    /*
    console.log({
        'window scroll':$('window').scrollTop(), 
        'scroll var': scroll, 
        'view scroll':$('#view').scrollTop(),
        'view height':$('#view').height(),
        'ls': last_scroll 
    });
    //*/
    if(last_scroll != $('#content').scrollTop()){ //check for new scroll
        last_scroll = $('#content').scrollTop()
        $('#content').scrollTop($('#content').scrollTop() + scroll);

        $(this).scrollTop(0);
        //console.log(e, 'scrolling');
    }
})
```

Comment: it's actually kinda hard to do the reverse, because `scroll` won't be fired if the window scrollTop is 0

Comment: Thank you for the advice dunli. I'll keeping looking into this. I also added the function below to reset the scroll back to the top of the page on page refresh.
$(window).on('load', function(){
 $("#content, html, body").animate({scrollTop: 0}, 500);
});

Comment: I also figured out that the above refresh function doesn't work well in chrome Version 46.0.2490.80 m. I had to perform a browser detect and add a separate function for chrome ONLY browsers. $(document).ready(function() {
//$(window).on('load', function(){
    //$.browser.chrome = /chrom(e|ium)/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());
    if(/chrom(e|ium)/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase())) {
 $(window).on('beforeunload', function() {
        $(window).scrollTop(0);
 });
 } else {
 $('#content,html,body').animate({scrollTop: 0 }, 500);
 };
//});
});